# Why does RecyclerView getAdapterPosition() return -1?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently learning android and first time adding swipe to delete functionality to the RecyclerView. I came across the following theory regarding to the swiping functionality but i am unable to understand the reason discussed below as to why getAdapterPosition will return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION.

> - When adapter contents change (and you call notify***) RecyclerView requests a new layout.
> - From that moment, until layout system decides to calculate a new layout (<16 ms), the layout
>     position and adapter position may not match because layout has not reflected adapter changes yet.
> - If you are calling notifyDataSetChanged, it invalidates everything, RecyclerView does not know
>     that ViewHolder's adapter position until next layout is calculated.
> - In that case, getAdapterPosition will return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION (-1)
> - If you've called notifyItemInserted(0), the getAdapterPosition of ViewHolder which was
>     previously at position 0 will start returning 1 immediately.
> - As long as you are dispatching granular notify events, you are always in good state (we know
>     adapter position even though new layout is not calculated yet).

Can someone please explain the above reason and the solution in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

`-1` means the scroll could not be computed or the actual position is not valid (in between).

The solution is ignore it

```
if (getAdapterPosition() == -1) return;
```